# Can you inject variables into the text when using Zend_Translate in plural mode

Tags: zend-framework, zend-translate, plural

I'm trying to use Zend_translate in a situation where I have to inject a variable value into the resulting string and have the string respect plural form. Using the regular (non-plural) view helper $this->translate() in a view script I can inject a variable into the string:

```
$this->translate('You have %1$s questions to answer', 3) 
// would result in "You have 3 questions to answer" being output
```

But how do I do this when using what Zend calls the modern way of plural notation? Apparently the $this->translate() view helper itself does not support the plural notation, instead I have to call

```
$this->translate()->getTranslator()->translate( 
    array('You have %1$s question to answer', 
    'You have %1$s questions to answer', $someNr ) 
)
```

But at that point I only have the plural string with the variable placeholder, I don't have the string with an injected value. In other words, what I'm getting is:

> You have %1$s questions to answer

What I want is

> You have 2 questions to answer

So the question is, does Zend_Translate somehow support this way of using plural? I.e. inject a variable value into the pluralized string? Or do I have to go with splitting up the string before and after the plural form, translate each separately and then concatenate at output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller (or elsewhere):

```
<?php
        $translate = new Zend_Translate (array (
            'adapter' => 'Zend_Translate_Adapter_Array',
            'content' => array (
                'test' => 'You have %1$s %2$s to answer'
            ),
            'locale' => 'en'
        ));
```

In the view:

```
<?php
$x = 1;
echo $this->translate ('test', $x, $this->translate (array (
    'question', 
    'questions', 
    $x 
)));
?>
```

But you probably want to have a look at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.plurals.html for a more intelligent way to do this.

Comment: Failure to understand the Zend documentation is what brought me here ;) Anyway, I'll accept this as the correct answer because in my case it does actually solve the problem in a better way than what I had. However, it still feels a bit hackish to have to call translate twice...